# Pass block to partial in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've this code which I'm trying to call from my view, without success.

```
# app/viwes/admin/index.html.haml
= panel title: "My title" do
  %h2 Hello!

# app/helpers/admin/suggestion_helper.rb
module Admin::SuggestionHelper
  def panel(locals, &block)
    render({partial: "admin/shared/panel"}, locals, &block)
  end
end

# app/views/admin/shared/_panel.html.haml
%h1= title
%div= yield
```

This results in this error `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`, why is that?

I'm using Rails `4.0.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using this code

```
def panel(locals, &block)
  render(layout: "admin/shared/panel", locals: locals, &block)
end
```

I replaced the `partial` key with `layout`, which solved the problem.